# How to remove the path to get the filename

Tags: c

How does one remove the path of a filepath, leaving only the filename?

I want to extract only the filename from a fts_path and store this in a char *fileName.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a function to remove the path on POSIX-style (`/`-separated) pathnames:

```
char *base_name(const char *pathname)
{
    char *lastsep = strrchr(pathname, '/');
    return lastsep ? lastsep+1 : pathname;
}
```

If you need to support legacy systems with odd path separators (like MacOS 9 or Windows), you might need to adapt the above to search for multiple possible separators. For example on Windows, both `/` and `\` are path separators and any mix of them can be used.

Answer (score 5):

You want [`basename(3)`](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/basename/).

Comment: I would recommend never touching `basename` due to the GNU controversy over how it's supposed to behave (they make it intentionally non-POSIX-conforming by default) and instead just rolling your own.

Comment: Actually I forgot the other reason, perhaps even better, not to touch it: the POSIX version of `basename` is specified to possibly clobber its input, meaning you can't safely call it without making a temporary copy of your pathname, which you then can't safely free or modify until you're done using the results of `basename`. And `basename` is also allowed to use static storage, meaning it might not be safe in a multi-threaded program.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <libgen.h>

int main(void)
{
    char * path = "/homes/mk08/Desktop/lala.c";
    char * tmp  = strdup(path);

    if(tmp) {
        printf("%s\n", basename(tmp));
        free(tmp);
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

This will output:

```
lala.c
```

Comment: Actually this program invokes undefined behavior by modifying a string literal. Per POSIX, *The basename() function may modify the string pointed to by path, and may return a pointer to static storage that may then be overwritten by a subsequent call to basename().*

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there is a less roundabout way of doing this, but you could always search through the filepath (I assume it is stored as a char array?), get the position of the final '\', and then erase everything prior to that.

Edit: See R's comment.

Comment: This would assume the program is running on Windows. A more agnostic approach is to simply use `basename()`.

Comment: This is actually the only correct solution, but you need to adapt it to also support `/` (which is *also* a path separator on Windows) and to ignore `\` as a path separator on all other systems.

Comment: I would define in your `config.h` or equivalent something like `#define ALT_PATH_SEP '\\'` on Windows, and leave it undefined on other systems. Then your code can do `#ifdef ALT_PATH_SEP`. Encoding knowledge about particular platforms into your source files is very bad practice; instead factor it out into the build-time config/build scripts.